# Uniqueness of determinant and trace as polynomial invariants?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $I : \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial that is invariant under the action of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ by conjugation on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.  Is $I$ just a polynomial in the trace and determinant functions?  More exactly, does there exist $f \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ so that $I(A) = f(\mathrm{tr}(A),\det(A))$ for all $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$?

I suppose that maybe the other coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are maybe such "polynomial invariants" of linear transformations that maybe can not be expressed in terms of the trace and determinant but I do not know about that.

Comment: Indeed these other coefficients are invariants, as you say. The real question is whether all invariants are polynomial functions of them?

Comment: $I$ is a polynomial in the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, which are algebraically independent.

Comment: Try para 2.3 of this: https://math.unibas.ch/uploads/x4epersdb/files/primernew.pdf